# PHP SoapClient Fault when there is response

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am making a SoapCall and currently struggling with a SoapFault:

> SoapFault: Client - SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules

The request is done this way:

```
$soapCallArgs[]['REQUEST_ID'] = $childProcessId;
try {
  $response = $soapClientOrder->__soapCall('GetSaleOrder',$soapCallArgs);
} catch (SoapFault $ex) {
  print 'SoapFault: ' . $ex->faultcode . ' - ' . $ex->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

The `$childProcessId` value (let's say 9999) does exists in the ERP that the webservice is consulting, then it should return some response, but instead I get the mentioned soapfault.

The curious thing is that when I enter an int (let's say 5, which doesn't exists in the ERP) instead of the `$childProcessId`, I do get a response (empty response, because the id 5 doesn't exists in the database).

I'm calling other webservices in the same ERP and all of them works fine. It's just this one that gets a fault when it has to return values.

Any advice would help, thanks a lot.

Just as an additional note, following, the WSDL and the requested php-formed XML:
WSDL

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns1:ParametroEntrada xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">
            <ns1:REQUEST_ID></ns1:REQUEST_ID>
        </ns1:ParametroEntrada>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Requested XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ParametroEntrada>
            <ns1:REQUEST_ID>5</ns1:REQUEST_ID>
        </ns1:ParametroEntrada>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.

In the XSD of the response, one of the parameters was set to double but the response was a string. I don't know why it wasn't validated in the insertion in the first place.

Thanks.